# Unsupported format or combination of formats) ,FindContours

Tags: python, opencv

I want to count the cars by using haar cascade.

```
#import libraries of python opencv
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import gc
import uuid
import datetime
import time
import csv

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v3.mp4')

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml') 
W = cap.get(3)
H = cap.get(4)
areaTH = 700

 H1 = (H/2)+10
W1 = W/2
mx = 0
my = 30

while (cap.isOpened()):
#capture frame by frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

#convert video into gray scale of each frames

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#detect cars in the video
cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 3)


#to draw arectangle in each cars 
for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)      

#display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('video', frame)
#press Q on keyboard to exit
if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

Line1 = np.array([[20,H1],[310,H1]], np.int32).reshape((-1,1,2))
frame = cv2.polylines(frame,[Line1],False,(0,0,255),thickness=5)
fram, contours0, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(frame,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours0:
   # cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, -1, (0,255,0), 2, 8)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    #print ('Area : '+str(area))

    if area > areaTH:
        #################
        #   TRACKING    #
        #################            
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy), 3, (255,0,0), -1)            
        img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        #print ('H1 : '+str(H1))
        print('cy : '+str(cy))

        if (cy >= 147) and (cy<= 155):
            Vehicles = Vehicles + 1
            Line1 = np.array([[200,H1],[880,H1]], 
    np.int32).reshape((-1,1,2))
            frame = cv2.polylines(frame,[Line1],False,(255,0,0),thickness=5)


        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

   #Abort and exit with 'Q' or ESC
   k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
   if k == 27:
    break

cap.release() #release video file
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I convert the image properly to gray-scale and successfully drawn a line on the frame the problem is that I am getting  this error

> error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\build\3_4_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:199: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

when ever i pass a variable 'frame' in this code line can somebody help me to solve this error thanx

```
fram, contours0, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(frame,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: Is it possible to give us a case that does not have all of your code, but only the relevant part where the error is showing up? Moreover, your error message says what is going on: At line 199, the format passed in as a parameter is not supported.

Comment: This error is generate because the data type of your is not of type `uint8` or have channels.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) for `cv2.findContour()`

**image** – *Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1’s. Zero pixels remain 0’s, so the image is treated as binary . You can use compare() , inRange() , threshold() , adaptiveThreshold() , Canny() , and others to create a binary image out of a grayscale or color one. The function modifies the image while extracting the contours. If mode equals to CV_RETR_CCOMP or CV_RETR_FLOODFILL, the input can also be a 32-bit integer image of labels (CV_32SC1).*

Try this line to scale the pixels

```
image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at OpenCV documentation you see that function `cv2.findContour()` requires monochrome images. You pass `frame` which is still in 3 channels. You should use the `gray` variable instead (`cv2.findContours(gray,...)`.